# Fuzzy directory tree deduplication

Tags: duplicate-files

I'm looking for some software that is able to make deduplication on tree like directory level. If I have following two folders:

```
/folder1
/folder1/subfolder1/file1
/folder1/subfolder2/file2
/folder1/subfolder3/file3


/folder2
/folder2/subfolder1/file1
/folder2/subfolder2/file2
/folder2/subfolder3/file3
```

Then requested software should categorize both folders with 100% match (same structure and content). But if 2nd folder looks like this:

```
/folder2
/folder2/subfolder1/file1
/folder2/subfolder2/file2
/folder2/AnotherFile3
```

Then requested should print some similarity between two folders (different structure and content).

I'm looking preferably for multi platform solution but either Windows or Linux would be OK. Requested software should be capable to crawl whole disk and print duplicates with some specific criteria e.g. more than 90% in structure or content etc.

Comment: Start by looking at [Meld](https://meldmerge.org/) or on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools)

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica 1. meld compares two folders (maybe three) 2. meld cannot do fuzzy matching

Comment: Sorry about that two folder (tree)s are enough for your example, but obviously not what you are looking for (+1). Good luck with your search